# Error with "RewriteEngine On" in .htaccess file on web server

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bloco/(.*)$ bloco.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^bloco/(.*)/$ bloco.php?id=$1
```

My .htaccess file have that configuration, work well on my local server but at web server dont work...

local:
domain.com/bloco/590

web server:
domain.com/bloco/?id=590

right now (not working...)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bloco/(.*)(/?)$ /carnaval/blocosderua/bloco.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php

php_value allow_url_fopen 1
php_value allow_url_include 1
```

any help?

Comment: Sounds like mod_rewrite is not enabled on your remote server.

Comment: i cant get the parameter "id" at domain.com/bloco/590

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, i'm! Other rules are working

Comment: The -indexes option will only disalow people to request a directory listing. You might want to consider removing php_value allow_url_fopen 1
php_value allow_url_include 1 These are not really safe to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your RewriteRule to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bloco/(.*)(/?)$ /bloco.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This assumes `bloco.php` is in your root. If it is not, you will need to specify the path to it:

```
RewriteRule ^bloco/(.*)(/?)$ /path/to/bloco.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all hosting companies allow you to use the rewrite engine. If your getting an error try to see if it also does with only the RewriteEngine On rule. If it does I'm afraid your not allowed to use it.

As for the rules they look fine to me.

Greets Michael

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include Options +FollowSymLinks at the top of your .htaccess. Otherwise this will need to be configured in your httpd.conf.

This will basically allow you to override configuration values in your .htaccess.

Comment: not working http://pura.rioguiaoficial.com.br/carnaval/blocosderua/bloco/1 (only at local server)